# Step up or down one div from located tag that contains a specific value using Scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to retrieve the price text from inside the custom-control / label / font style. The only way to identify which value the price belongs to is the data-number `data-number="025.00286R"`. The letter at the end is the only element that differentiates the different control section divs.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" data-number="025.00286R" name="itemSelected[]" value="7684cd019b98489eb330010000039848" id="checkbox-7684cd019b98489eb330010000039848">
   <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-7684cd019b98489eb330010000039848">
      <meta itemprop="price" content="676.0512">
      <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
      €676.05
      </font></font>
   </label>
</div>
```

I use this code to retrieve the total number of `data-number`'s within the page:

```
box_contents = response.css('div[class*="mad-article-list-box"]').re(r"[0-9]+.\d+[0-9][A-Z]+")
box_contents = list(dict.fromkeys(box_contents))
```

So that box contents are presented in a list (for each number in the list there is an identical `custom control` class:

```
['025.00286GA', '025.00286GV', '025.00286NWA', '025.00286NW', '025.00286NWV', '025.00286R']
```

The problem now is that the `<input type="checkbox"` does not contain any children divs, and I need the nested text contents of the div below it. `<label class="custom-control-label"`

I can locate the `<input` with:

```
response.xpath('//input[contains(@data-number, "' + box_contents[0] + '")]')
```

However, now I need to either step up one in the xpath after locating the `<input type="checkbox"` or step down 1 in the xpath. After that it is easy to extract all the nested text and the value that I am looking for `€676.05`. How would I go about doing this? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you can select the input that you want then use the Adjacent sibling combinator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to select the following `label`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through each of the `div` elements with the `custom-control` classes individually and pull the information for each checkbox and label one at a time, instead of gathering them all each at once.  Then the two pieces of data will already be paired up since you will be iterating one pair at a time, and since you will be starting at a parent element to both data elements, finding the correct path to each element is more straightforward.

For example:

```
html = """
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" data-number="025.00286R" name="itemSelected[]" value="7684cd019b98489eb330010000039848" id="checkbox-7684cd019b98489eb330010000039848">
   <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-7684cd019b98489eb330010000039848">
      <meta itemprop="price" content="676.0512">
      <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
      €676.05
      </font></font>
   </label>
</div>
"""

import parsel
selector = parsel.Selector(html)

for control in selector.xpath("//div[@class='custom-control custom-checkbox']"):
    data_number = control.xpath("./input/@data-number").get()
    price = control.xpath(".//meta/@content").get()
    print({"data_number": data_number, "price": price })
```

Output

```
{'data_number': '025.00286R', 'price': '676.0512'}
```